# Is this a good method for counting threads in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, system, hardware

I've been looking for a reliable way to count the number threads accessible to a program to be used. I didn't want to use a constant though and make the assumption that every system had the same number of accessible threads. I've devised this method of trying to figure it out. Is it a good method?

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

struct list
{
    void *data;
    list *next;

    list(list *x = nullptr)
    {
        data = x;
        next = nullptr;
    }
    void add()
    {
        next = new list;
    }
};

void sleepo(int xz)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 10000000; x++)
    {
        xz++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int count = 1;
    list *iterator = new list;

    cout << "Attmepting to count threads..." << endl;

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            iterator->data = new thread(sleepo, count);
            iterator->add();
            iterator = iterator->next;
            count++;
        }
        catch(system_error)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    cout << "There are " << count << " threads." << endl;
}
```

Comment: This number usually isn't a constant; it may depend on the exact amount of resources (mainly memory) available on the system at any given instant.  Just because you were able to start 5000 threads in one test today, is no guarantee that you will succeed in doing the same tomorrow.  So any program still has to be able to handle the possibility that creating a thread will fail.

Comment: Note also that it is an error to exit the program before all threads have been either joined or detached.

Comment: It generally isn't *useful* to count the number of threads that can be created. For CPU-bound work, use `sched_getaffinity` on Linux, and count the bits. For thread-based I/O (ick!), just create as many as are needed; chances are you'll hit other limits first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no standard way to count the number of threads that have been started by a program. Neither in the C++ standard, nor for example in the POSIX standard.

> I've devised this method of trying to figure it out. Is it a good method?

If you are in control of the creation of every thread, then that would work just fine. But it won't work if you for example use a library that also creates threads unless you can somehow inject code that increments your counter.

In order to know the current number of threads instead of total number of started threads, you would need to decrement the counter each time you join.

Comment: _"there is no standard way"_ -- is this true? I would have thought that a `thread_local` variable could be used that has a constructor action that adds to a global object with `static` storage duration. Effectively creating a static-counter only executed on thread-entrance.

Comment: @Human-Compiler It won't work universally, since you must odr-use the thread local variable in each thread for it to be constructed. Hence, like in the OP's code, you must be in control of the threads. It's subtly different though that you don't need to be in control of the creation of the thread, but rather in control of what the thread does.